# Returning all Salesforce contacts associated with an account via query from third-party site

Tags: salesforce, survey, soql

I'm using Survey Gizmo and I want to pull in all contact emails associated with an account.

This query works, but it only pulls in the first contact and I need them all:

```
SELECT Id,Contact.Email FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = 'Insert_Account_Id_Here'
```

How can I pull in more than one contact?

If that's not possible, is it possible to specifically pull in contact "N"? Then, question 1 could pull in contact 1, question 2 could pull in contact 2 and so forth.

Thanks... I'm new to this so let me know if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Select id,(select Email from contacts) from Acount  where id =:'acountLd
for (contact con:acc.Contacts){ con.Email....}